# Nested for loop producing more number of values than expected-Python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

Background:I have two catalogues consisting of positions of spatial objects. My aim is to find the similar ones in both catalogues with a maximum difference in angular distance of certain value. One of them is called *bss* and another one is called *super*.

Here is the full code I wrote

```
import numpy as np
def crossmatch(bss_cat, super_cat, max_dist):
    matches=[]
    no_matches=[]
    def find_closest(bss_cat,super_cat):
        dist_list=[]
        def angular_dist(ra1, dec1, ra2, dec2):
            r1 = np.radians(ra1)
            d1 = np.radians(dec1)
            r2 = np.radians(ra2)
            d2 = np.radians(dec2)
            a = np.sin(np.abs(d1-d2)/2)**2
            b = np.cos(d1)*np.cos(d2)*np.sin(np.abs(r1 - r2)/2)**2
            rad = 2*np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a + b))
            d = np.degrees(rad)
            return d
        for i in range(len(bss_cat)):  #The problem arises here
            for j in range(len(super_cat)):
                distance =  angular_dist(bss_cat[i][1], bss_cat[i][2], super_cat[j][1], super_cat[j][2]) #While this is supposed to produce single floating point values, it produces numpy.ndarray consisting of three entries
                dist_list.append(distance) #This list now contains numpy.ndarrays instead of numpy.float values 
                for k in range(len(dist_list)):
                    if dist_list[k] < max_dist:
                        element = (bss_cat[i], super_cat[j], dist_list[k])
                        matches.append(element)
                    else:
                        element = bss_cat[i]
                        no_matches.append(element)
    return (matches,no_matches)
```

When put seperately, the function `angular_dist(ra1, dec1, ra2, dec2)` produces a single numpy.float value as expected. But when used inside the for loop in this `crossmatch(bss_cat, super_cat, max_dist)` function, it produces numpy.ndarrays instead of numpy.float. I've stated this inside the code also. I don't know where the code goes wrong. Please help

Comment: If angular_dist returns another shape output maybe the input was another shape.

Comment: Both bss_cat and super_cat consist of tuples having float values. That's why I have put it like bss_cat[i][1]. Also, I worked on a similar problem before but it had only one for loop. That's why I suspected a problem in the for loop